# The name Huxley

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I came across the name "Huxley" and I wanted to know what it meant, however I came across different meanings and I would like to know if you know the real truth a little better.

Some places only referred it to author Aldous Huxley, some said it means someone who came from Huxley, another said "from hughs meadow" and the last place which was completely unofficial or dependable place said "inhospitable place". the latter is the one I actually most care about and I would love to know if that is the meaning somehow, however all I found it in is list of so-called bad names because of their meanings but no where when searching for the name definition.

Can anyone clarify this matter?

Comment: The only meaning I am familiar with is the author Aldous Huxley.  Your question could be strengthened, and would be more answerable, if you provided links or at least quotes for some of those other uses.

Comment: Of course @aparente001 .
They all came out of googling "Huxley name meaning"
http://www.meaning-of-names.com/english-names/huxley.asp
 , http://nameberry.com/babyname/Huxley

and there are plenty other links that show the same meanings.